# What is the best compression utility for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, zip

What compression utility can you recommend that supports zip, rar, tar, etc... like 7zip and FilZip on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal recommendation is [BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/) for a small price and the ability to create archives. A free alternative is [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) but this is limited to archive extraction only.

Comment: I choose your answer, because of BetterZip that is a good software. The only problem it's not free as I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Stuffit Expander](http://www.stuffit.com/mac-expander.html) is a good one that I hear a lot about. The built-in Archive Utility will hand just about every thing except for RAR files. For that I would use [UnRARX](http://www.unrarx.com%20%22UnrarX), which is also free.

Comment: The built in utility cannot handle 7-Zip amongst other formats.

Comment: Fair enough. It's good enough for basic zips and tars but if you need more Stuffit handles it and it's free on the app store or as a stand alone. The option to set it as default is right there in it's settings as well which is nice

Comment: The built-in utility also can't handle zip files with AES-256 encryption, a limitation it shares with Windows and which is why everyone uses 7zip ;)

Answer (score 0):

I like [Archiver](http://archiverapp.com/) (formerly known as Rucksack). But it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

I found Keka that is some different to use, but solve the problem. And Unarchiver is a good choice to decompress too.

Thanks all!